# Locating people by roleId

Tags: c#, beginner, linq, xml

Basically, I'm trying to find all active people with a `roleId` of 3 (analyst id). But I want to exclude ids that were created as test analysts, i.e. "130", "252", etc. I see that I'm repeating the part to exclude the test ids. Also, I'm repeating the part about the `roleId`. Isn't there a way to optimize it? My query works fine, but I'm trying to optimize to make it more DRY.

Here's what my code looks like (I've labeled where I think the code can be optimized):

```
from people in xDoc.Descendants("People")
where (int?) Convert.ToInt16(people.Element("active").Value) == 1 &&
    (int?)Convert.ToInt16(people.Element("id").Value) != 130 &&  // <-- to optimize
    (int?)Convert.ToInt16(people.Element("id").Value) != 252 &&  // <-- to optimize
    (int?)Convert.ToInt16(people.Element("id").Value) != 264 &&  // <-- to optimize
    (int?)Convert.ToInt16(people.Element("id").Value) != 302 &&  // <-- to optimize
    people.Descendants("roleIds").Descendants("int")
        .Select(p => (int?)Convert.ToInt16(p.Value)).FirstOrDefault() == 3  // <-- to optimize
select new PeopleClass
{
    ResAnId = (int) Convert.ToInt16(people.Element("id").Value),
    DpInit = (string)people.Element("clientCode").Value,
    ResAnFName = (string)people.Element("firstName").Value,
    ResAnLName = (string)people.Element("lastName").Value,
    ResAnName = String.Format("{0} {1}", (string)people.Element("firstName").Value,
        (string)people.Element("lastName").Value),
    RoleId = people.Descendants("roleIds").Descendants("int")
        .Select(p => (int?) Convert.ToInt16(p.Value)).FirstOrDefault(),  // <-- to optimize
    DivisionId = (int?) Convert.ToInt16(people.Element("divisionId").Value)
}).ToList();
```

If you're interested, here's my XML feed:

```xml
<People>
  <id>269</id>
  <dummy>false</dummy>
  <firstName>Steve</firstName>
  <lastName>Jobs</lastName>
  <initial></initial>
  <title>CEO</title>
  <active>1</active>
  <analystPosition></analystPosition>
  <clientCode>SJ</clientCode>
  <clientCode2></clientCode2>
  <divisionId>2</divisionId>
  <updatedBy>245</updatedBy>
  <associates>
    <Associate>
      <analystId>269</analystId>
      <associateId>257</associateId>
      <rank>0</rank>
    </Associate>
  </associates>
  <roleIds>
    <int>3</int>
    <int>4</int>
    <int>13</int>
  </roleIds>
</People>
```

Comment: Please explain what the query is doing.

Comment: Why is there so much casting going on?

Comment: I'm fairly a novice programmer.  I thought that's programming should be done.  I'm guessing that I should only do casting once, right?

Answer (score 7):

You can introduce [*range variables*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) to hold data which you need several times in your query:

```
var analystRoleId = 3;
var testAnalystIds = new[] { 130, 252, 264, 302 };

var activeAnalysts = 
    from p in xdoc.Descendants("People")
    let id = (int)p.Element("id")
    let isActive = (int)p.Element("active") == 1                        
    let isAnalyst = p.Descendants("roleIds").Elements().Any(e => (int)e == analystRoleId)
    let firstName = (string)p.Element("firstName")
    let lastName = (string)p.Element("lastName")
    where isActive && isAnalyst && !testAnalystIds.Contains(id)
    select new PeopleClass {
        ResAnId = id,
        DpInit = (string)p.Element("clientCode"),
        ResAnFName = firstName,
        ResAnLName = lastName,
        ResAnName = $"{firstName} {lastName}",
        RoleId = analystRoleId,
        DivisionId = (int?)p.Element("divisionId")
    };
```

Also

- You can use interpolated strings instead of `String.Format`
- I believe `id` always should present in your file and it will not be null. There is no need to cast this value to nullable
- I believe you should check all role ids for verifying whether person is analyst. But you can use `FirstOrDeafult` as well
- You don't need to query for roleId second time - if person matched *where* clause then it's analyst and you know his role id
- You don't need to access `Value` property of XElement. It's better to use explicit cast operator. Otherwise you can get NullReferenceExceptions
- If you can change implementation of `PeopleClass` then start with renaming it to `Person` and give more descriptive names to its fields. You can also remove backing storage from `ResAndName` filed and make it calculated on the fly.

Comment: I've never seen this bit of code before:  `ResAnName = $"{firstName} {lastName}"`.  Actually, I was surprised that this worked.  Thanks for opening my eyes to the new paradigm.  Also, thank for `Value` pointer.  I thought that I had to use `Value` when accessing XML fields.  I'm not sure I understand your last point.  Would you mind explaining, please?

Comment: This is a nice example how useful `let` can be.

Comment: @inquisitive_one by last point I mean that you can create class named Person without `class` suffix, and give it properties with names `Id`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, and property `Name` which is implemented as `get { return $"{FirstName} {LastName}"; }`

Answer (score 4):

The query as shown in @[Sergey Berezovskiy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/153091/59161)'s answer is ok for a one time query but if you are going to create the `People` class more then once from `XElement`s then you should encapsulate it and let the `People` class *parse* the `XElement`

```
class People
{
    private People(XElement xPeople)
    {
        id = (int)xPeople.Element("id");
        ..other properties
    }

    public int id { get; set; }

    .. other properties

    public static People Parse(XElement xPeople) => new People(xPeople);
}
```

You could then simplify the query to

```
var activeAnalysts = 
    from p in xdoc.Descendants("People").Select(People.Parse)    
    where p.isActive && p.isAnalyst && !testAnalystIds.Contains(p.id)
    select new p;
```

*Other then this I support the suggestions given in the other answer.*